# How to get mean of column of np.arrays every n rows, and then add mean to new column for each member of group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df of np.arrays like this:

```
x           y    
0      [2,0,1]
1      [0,0,4]
2      [0,0,1]
3      [2,0,2]
4      [1,0,1]
5      [0,0,2]
6      [0,1,1]
7      [0,0,0]
8      [0,0,1]
```

I want to get the mean array element-wise, I imagine using something like np.mean(x, axis=0) of ever 3 rows. The means should look like this:

```
       [.66,   0,    2]
       [  1,   0, 1.66]
       [. 0, .33,  .66]
```

I then want to add the mean for each group to a new column where the value repeats for each row member in the group. It should look like this:

```
x           y    
0      [2,0,1]       [.66,   0,    2]
1      [0,0,4]       [.66,   0,    2]
2      [0,0,1]       [.66,   0,    2]
3      [2,0,2]       [  1,   0, 1.66]
4      [1,0,1]       [  1,   0, 1.66]
5      [0,0,2]       [  1,   0, 1.66]
6      [0,1,1]       [. 0, .33,  .66]
7      [0,0,0]       [. 0, .33,  .66]
8      [0,0,1]       [. 0, .33,  .66]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a standard RangeIndex, we can [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) to turn `y` into a DataFrame, [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) every 3 rows and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) to mean, then return the DataFrame to a Series of lists:

```
df['new_col'] = (
    df['y'].apply(pd.Series)  # TUrn into DataFrame
        .groupby(df.index // 3)  # Group rows into groups of 3
        .transform('mean')  # Calculate mean per group
        .apply(list, axis=1)  # Make DataFrame a Series of lists
)
```

`df`:

```
   x          y                                        new_col
0  0  [2, 0, 1]                 [0.6666666666666666, 0.0, 2.0]
1  1  [0, 0, 4]                 [0.6666666666666666, 0.0, 2.0]
2  2  [0, 0, 1]                 [0.6666666666666666, 0.0, 2.0]
3  3  [2, 0, 2]                 [1.0, 0.0, 1.6666666666666667]
4  4  [1, 0, 1]                 [1.0, 0.0, 1.6666666666666667]
5  5  [0, 0, 2]                 [1.0, 0.0, 1.6666666666666667]
6  6  [0, 1, 1]  [0.0, 0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666]
7  7  [0, 0, 0]  [0.0, 0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666]
8  8  [0, 0, 1]  [0.0, 0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666]
```

If needed [`DataFrame.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) can be chained in as well:

```
df['new_col'] = (
    df['y'].apply(pd.Series)  # TUrn into DataFrame
        .groupby(df.index // 3)  # Group rows into groups of 3
        .transform('mean')  # Calculate mean per group
        .round(2)  # Round to 2 Decimal Places
        .apply(list, axis=1)  # Make DataFrame a Series of lists
)
```

`df`:

```
   x          y            new_col
0  0  [2, 0, 1]   [0.67, 0.0, 2.0]
1  1  [0, 0, 4]   [0.67, 0.0, 2.0]
2  2  [0, 0, 1]   [0.67, 0.0, 2.0]
3  3  [2, 0, 2]   [1.0, 0.0, 1.67]
4  4  [1, 0, 1]   [1.0, 0.0, 1.67]
5  5  [0, 0, 2]   [1.0, 0.0, 1.67]
6  6  [0, 1, 1]  [0.0, 0.33, 0.67]
7  7  [0, 0, 0]  [0.0, 0.33, 0.67]
8  8  [0, 0, 1]  [0.0, 0.33, 0.67]
```

---

If index is not standard RangeBased index we can create our own with [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
df['new_col'] = (
    df['y'].apply(pd.Series)
        .groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3)  # Create Range index based df length
        .transform('mean')
        .apply(list, axis=1)
)
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    'y': [[2, 0, 1], [0, 0, 4], [0, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2], [1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2],
          [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
})
```

Comment: Also `pd.DataFrame(df['y'].tolist()).assign(k=np.arange(len(df))//3).groupby('k').transform('mean').agg(list,1)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
(df.assign(m = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))//3)
          .agg({'y': lambda x: x.map(np.array).mean().round(2).tolist()})
          .rename(lambda x: x*3)
          .squeeze())
 .ffill())
```